# Multiple audio outputs in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, audio

I am looking to build a PC box that can play up to 16 audio files(mp3/wav) out to 16 analog devices(think of it as 16 sets of speakers).  There will be a one to one relationship for audio file to analog output. The solution that is being presented to be hardware wise is to use multiple sound cards, so my question is, is there a library available that will let me play an audio file to a specific sound card / channel?

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to word this question, and realized you'd already asked it.  The answers have made my heart grow two sizes today.

Comment: I actually ended up going with NAudio for my solution.  It does was I need it to do.

Comment: would you mind to share some of your work? I am trying something similar, found NAudio, but my impression is that you are always sitting on top of the wave out facility which supports a maximum of two channels in the current implementation.

Comment: We are building a communication simulation system.  It will allow for up to 8 different audio streams (one side conversation) to be send out 8 different communication radios.  Currently I am using 8 usb audio cards to control each of the audio streams.  The hard part was actually determining which usb card was linked to which device ID that is used by NAudio.

You are right that NAudio basically just sits on top of the wave out Win32 API's.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I see that we try to achieve something different. I want to play one audio stream on eight channels (assuming a 7.1 sound system) simultaneously but adjust the volume on every speaker separately to simulate the "location" of the stream in the room. In the meantime I was successfully using bass.net -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624985/how-to-realize-a-multi-channel-audio-pre-mixer-in-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the BASS library can do this.
http://www.un4seen.com

C# wrappers are also available, a commercial one:
[Bass.NET](http://bass.radio42.com/)
and an excellent alternative open source C# wrapper for Bass:
[ManagedBass](https://github.com/ManagedBass) by [Mathew Sachin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5377194/mathew-sachin)

Answer (score 2):

I found this one while I was looking as well.
http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/) should do what you're looking for.  It's also an extremely fast, solid and popular library overall.